# QML solution for a structured layout not using a GridView or ListView but using a c++ model

Tags: qt, qml, qt5, qtquick2

I am trying to think of a way to represent some items in a very structured way by using `Row` and `Column` only. I got the idea from Qt Widgets where you can do everything with Horizontal and Vertical layouts and have a beautiful UI. The issue is that I still want the data that is creating my QML items to come from c++, which entails a model of some sort. From what I know models can be only bound to `PathView`, `GridView` or `ListView`. Also that data will change dynamically based on some "add" and "remove" operations signaled by the QML UI. Is there a way to use `Row` and `Column` with a model?

Comment: `Row { Repeater { model: myModel; delegate: Rectangle { width: 10; height: 10 } } }`

Comment: that is if you only want to present your model in a row or column. what if the same model needs to be represented under different rows and columns. are multiple models needed at that point?

Comment: Yes, but it is an important addition to your list of things *"models can be only bound*". And the `Instantiator` is not less important.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let us assume your model shall populate a `Grid`, a `Row` and a `Column`:

```
ListModel {
    id: lm
    ListElement { target: "Grid"; content: "green" }
    ListElement { target: "Grid"; content: "blue" }
    ListElement { target: "Grid"; content: "yellow" }
    ListElement { target: "Grid"; content: "orange" }
    ListElement { target: "Row"; content: "green" }
    ListElement { target: "Row"; content: "blue" }
    ListElement { target: "Row"; content: "yellow" }
    ListElement { target: "Row"; content: "orange" }
    ListElement { target: "Column"; content: "green" }
    ListElement { target: "Column"; content: "blue" }
    ListElement { target: "Column"; content: "yellow" }
    ListElement { target: "Column"; content: "orange" }
}

Row {
    id: row
    spacing: 2
    anchors {
        top: parent.top
        left: parent.left
        right: parent.right
    }
}
Column {
    id: column
    spacing: 2
    anchors {
        top: row.bottom; topMargin: 2
        left: parent.left
        bottom: parent.bottom
    }
}
Grid {
    id: grid
    spacing: 2
    columns: 2
    anchors {
        top: row.bottom
        left: column.right
        right: parent.right
        bottom: parent.bottom
        margins: 102
    }
}
```

You can either use a `Repeater` like this:

```
Repeater {
    model: lm
    delegate:  Rectangle {
        width: 100
        height: 100
        parent: (target === "Grid" ? grid :
                   (target === "Row" ? row :
                      (target === "Column" ? column :
                         null)))
        color: content
    }
}
```

which may give you an warning:

> ```
> QQuickItem::stackAfter: Cannot stack after 0x3d5cb18, which must be a sibling
> ```

Or you can use the `Instantiator`, which will need to create an additional `QtObject` but instead you won't get any warning.

```
Instantiator {
    model: lm
    delegate: QtObject {
        property Item child: Rectangle {
        width: 100
        height: 100
        parent: (target === "Grid" ? grid :
                   (target === "Row" ? row :
                      (target === "Column" ? column :
                         null)))
        color: content
    }}
}
```

And you can even have multiple objects for one model entry...

```
Instantiator {
    model: lm
    delegate: QtObject {
        property Item child1: Rectangle {
        width: 100
        height: 100
        parent: (target === "Row" ? row :
                   (target === "Column" ? column :
                      null)) // If "Grid" this thing will be created but not shown.
        color: content
        }

        property Item gridItem: Button {
            width: 100
            height: 30
            text: content
            onClicked: rootWin.color = content
            parent: grid
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks for taking time to respond. it's gonna take me some time to integrate this into my solution, will get back here right after i do that